# Perl. Hash inside array inside hash. How to get values of inner hash?

Tags: perl, hash, nested

There is a simple code to query storm api

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON::XS;
use Try::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
my $status = $ua->get("http://lab7.local:8888/api/v1/topology/summary");
my $sts = $status->decoded_content;
my $coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;
my $out = try {my $output = $coder->decode($sts)} catch {undef};
print Dumper(\%$out);
```

The output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'topologies' => [
                        {
                          'encodedId' => 'subscriptions_lab_product-8-1452610838',
                          'workersTotal' => 1,
                          'status' => 'ACTIVE',
                          'uptime' => '35m 54s',
                          'name' => 'subscriptions_lab_product',
                          'id' => 'subscriptions_lab_product-8-1452610838',
                          'tasksTotal' => 342,
                          'executorsTotal' => 342
                        }
                      ]
    };
```

How can i get for example the 'id' value of inner hash?
OS: RHEL6.6
Perl: 5.10.1

Comment: See [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for info on creating and accessing a variety of complex data structures in Perl.

Comment: You mean like `$out->{topologies}->[0]->{id}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only one topology, it's simply what [@MattJacob already said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748694/perl-hash-inside-array-inside-hash-how-to-get-values-of-inner-hash#comment57243293_34748694).

```
$out->{topologies}->[0]->{id}
```

If there are more, you can iterate.

```
my @ids;
foreach my $topology ( @{ $out->{topologies} } ) {
  push @ids, $topology->{id};
}
```

Here is a visual explanation including free-hand circles.

[image]

First there is a hash reference that only has the single key *topologies*.

```
$out->{topologies};
```

Under that key, there is an array reference. The elements in that array reference are hash references, but there is only one. To get that first one, use the index `0`.

```
$out->{topologies}->[0];
```

Now you've got that hash reference with all the properties of the topology inside. You can use the key *id* to get the string on the right hand side of the dump.

```
$out->{topologies}->[0]->{id};
```

---

Also see [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: Thanks for visualized explanation. Btw it doesn't work with say but works with print.
Useless use of hash element in void context at ./storm_api.pl line 22.
Can't call method "say" on unblessed reference at ./storm_api.pl line 22.

Comment: @user That's because you have to `use feature 'say'` to get that keyword. I replaced that with an array operation instead.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question, you need to use the [dereference operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) (`->`):

```
$out->{topologies}->[0]->{id}
```

Technically, the arrow is optional between subscripts, so the line above could be rewritten as:

```
$out->{topologies}[0]{id}
```

But since you're asking the question in the first place, I would recommend reading [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) to get a solid foundation for references in Perl.

Comment: I wasn't sure about 5.10, so I checked http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/perlreftut.html#Arrow-Rule. The arrow is indeed already optional in that version. Didn't want to steal your answer btw. You were fast with your comment.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks, and no worries. I wrote the comment because I thought it was too simple for an answer, but then I realized that it does actually answer the question, so I expanded it into an answer.